# How to establish TOR connection in Java using SilverTunnel-NG?

Tags: java, tor

I tried to run [an example code](http://sourceforge.net/p/silvertunnel-ng/wiki/Sample%20Code%20%3A%20Check%20if%20Tor%20Connection%20works/). I included in my project following libraries:

- slf4j-jdk14-1.7.10.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar
- netlib-0.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
- bcprov-jdk15on-1.50.jar
- bcpkix-jdk15on-1.50.jar

And apparently it isn't enough because I got an error:

> INFO: Welcome to silvertunnel-ng.org Netlib (version 0.0.4-SNAPSHOT)
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spongycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider (...) at TorTest.main(TorTest.java:16)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

Where line 16 is (you can see the whole file in the example link):

```
final NetSocket topSocket = NetFactory.getInstance().getNetLayerById(NetLayerIDs.TOR_OVER_TLS_OVER_TCPIP).createNetSocket(null, null, TORCHECK_NETADDRESS);
```

I looked for an answer how to include this BouncyCastleProvider but all I got is a hint to include `bcprov-jdk15on-1.50.jar` and `bcpkix-jdk15on-1.50.jar` which I did.

Does anybody know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me (I used maven to bring the dependencies), and this is the list of dependencies I got

```
org.silvertunnel-ng:netlib:jar:0.0.3:compile
org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore:jar:4.1.2:compile
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2:compile
org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:jar:4.1.2:compile
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.2:compile
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.3:compile
org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.50:compile
org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.50:compile
org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
```

The only dependency I imported from maven is

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.silvertunnel-ng</groupId>
   <artifactId>netlib</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Interesingly, the class `org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider` isn't in any of the jars ang googling a bit I found that that class exists in an [unofficial fork of Bouncy Castle](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.madgag/scprov-jdk15/1.46.99.3-UNOFFICIAL-ROBERTO-RELEASE/org/spongycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider.java)... so maybe you got one of your libraries from that fork.

If you want I can put this up in github.

Comment: I've added that but an error occurred with different libraries. If you could put it on github it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used Augusto's answer to individually download the libraries listed by Maven.

Using a combination of the following got the [example code](http://sourceforge.net/p/silvertunnel-ng/wiki/Sample%20Code%20%3A%20Check%20if%20Tor%20Connection%20works/) working at least:

- [netlib 0.0.3.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/silvertunnel-ng/files/Releases/netlib-0.0.3.zip/download) from [SilverTunnel-NG git](http://sourceforge.net/projects/silvertunnel-ng)
- httpcore jar 4.1.2, httpclient jar 4.1.2 and httpmime jar 4.3 from the SilverTunnel-NG git [dependencies.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/silvertunnel-ng/files/dependencies.zip/download)
- [bcprov-jdk15on.jar](http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar) and [bcpkix-jdk15on.jar](http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcpkix-jdk15on-152.jar) from http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html
- [slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7.jar](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html) from http://www.slf4j.org/download.html

After testing successfully I then checked to see if this set of dependencies would work with netlib 0.0.4-SNAPSHOT, however this gave the same
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider` error.

Answer (score 0):

The Snapshot Version 0.0.4 of SilverTunnel-NG has been prepared to run on Android (still not working on Android) and one change needed was to use an uncrippled Version of BouncyCastle as Android has its own with the same package name. Thats why SpongyCastle has been introduced. It is just a copy of the original BouncyCastle but with a different name.

So for getting the 0.0.4-SNAPSHOT to run you need to get [spongycastle](https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/).

The snapshots of SilverTunnel are also deployed to Maven Central so it is possible that maven takes care of all the dependencies.